# change Tab based on HTML Select value

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

Could someone help me connect these bits of code.  I'm using Twitter bootstrap and I have a Dropdown list and when the user selects an item in the dropdown list I want to show the tab that corresponds to the item selected.

Here's my html code so far...

```
   <select>
     <option>Select...</option>
     <option value=1>Individual Investor</a></option>
     <option value=1>Joint Investors</option>
     <option value=3>Company Investor</option>
     <option value=1>Trust (Individual Trustees)</option>
     <option value=2>Trust (Corporate Trustees)</option>         
     <option value=1>SMSF (Individual Trustees)</option>
     <option value=2>SMSF (Corporate Trustees)</option>
   </select>

    <div class="tabbable"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#tab0" data-toggle="tab">Investor Details</a></li>
        <li class="hidden"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Individuals</a></li>
        <li class="hidden"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Joint</a></li>
        <li class="hidden"><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Company</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="tab-content">         
        <div class="active tab-pane" id="tab0">
          <div class="alert">               
            Select your Investor Type from the Dropdown list above
          </div>
            <legend>Investor Details</legend>
            <label>Select your Investor Type from the Dropdown list above</label>               
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
            <legend>Individual Investor Details</legend>
            <label>First Name</label>               
            <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
            <legend>Joint Investor Details</legend>
            <label>Both Names</label>               
            <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" placeholder="Enter both Names">
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
            <legend>Company Investor Details</legend>
            <label>Company Name</label>             
            <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" placeholder="Enter Company Name">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What do I need to get this to function?
thanks in advance.

Comment: I've put together a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/newL1406/VcFwd/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [jQuery Library](http://jquery.com/) to easily manipulate the DOM. It's pretty easy to learn, highly efficient & time-saving. It will also save you a lot of headache on cross-browser code issues...

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your HTML a little-bit, added ID to select tag and changed the values of options values.
If you are using Jquery this will work

```
  <select id="dropDown">
     <option>Select...</option>
     <option value="tab1">Individual Investor</a></option>
     <option value="tab2">Joint Investors</option>
     <option value="tab3">Company Investor</option>
     <option value="tab4">Trust (Individual Trustees)</option>
     <option value="tab5">Trust (Corporate Trustees)</option>         
     <option value="tab6">SMSF (Individual Trustees)</option>
     <option value="tab7">SMSF (Corporate Trustees)</option>
   </select>

<div class="tabbable"> <!-- Only required for left/right tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a href="#tab0" data-toggle="tab">Investor Details</a></li>
    <li class="hidden"><a href="#tab1" data-toggle="tab">Individuals</a></li>
    <li class="hidden"><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Joint</a></li>
    <li class="hidden"><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Company</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">         
    <div class="active tab-pane" id="tab0">
      <div class="alert">               
        Select your Investor Type from the Dropdown list above
      </div>
        <legend>Investor Details</legend>
        <label>Select your Investor Type from the Dropdown list above</label>               
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab1">
        <legend>Individual Investor Details</legend>
        <label>First Name</label>               
        <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab2">
        <legend>Joint Investor Details</legend>
        <label>Both Names</label>               
        <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" placeholder="Enter both Names">
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="tab3">
        <legend>Company Investor Details</legend>
        <label>Company Name</label>             
        <input class="input-xlarge" type="text" placeholder="Enter Company Name">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$("#dropDown").change(function() {          
        var value = $("#dropDown option:selected").val();
        $('#tabbable li).find(a[href=#'+value+']').click();
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an onchange event handler on your select list but you need to give it an ID first. Then using the value of the selected item as the index of the link to make the tab active you can use JQuery.

```
<select id="someSelect">
```

You also need an ID on the nav-tabs ul. This will allow you to see the highlighted tab button when you choose a different tab.

```
<ul id="someNavTabs" class="nav nav-tabs">
```

Then you can use JavaScript as following:

```
document.getElementById('someSelect').onchange = function () {
    var selectedValue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
    var selectedIndex = selectedValue; // added this variable for clarity
    $('#someNavTabs a:eq(' + selectedIndex + ')').tab('show');
};
```

If you want to do this without JQuery then more coding is required.

Comment: Cool, if this solution was what you used then mark it as the answer to your problem using the tick on the left thanks