# Grouped CSS Menu

Tags: html, css, menu

I apologize if this question already exist but I'm not sure what is this called to even search for the correct resources.

I'm trying to create a tabbed header menu for different groups of people. In a sense, each group has their own custom menu which may still share pages. What I'm trying to do is to make the navigation intuitive depending who the site visitor is (what is relevant to the visitor).

eg.

```
|   Student   |   Teacher   |   Parents   |
|             ----------------------------|
| Timetable, Homework, Activities ........|


|   Student   |   Teacher   |   Parents   |
|-------------|             |-------------|
| Homework, Schedule .....................|


|   Student   |   Teacher   |   Parents   |
|---------------------------|             |
| Timetable ..............................|
```

As you can see, the Student and Parent group menu both have "Timetable" page. The contents of the page is exactly the same (pointing to the same url). However, if a visitor accessed the Timetable page from the Student menu tab, when the page loads, the menu should show the navigation menu under the Student tab. Likewise if a visitor accessed the page via Parent tab.

Of course, I planned to add colours to the different tabs to further differentiate them, and even further dropdowns on certain items, but I'm stuck even at this preliminary stage.

Can anyone help enlighten me what is this feature called? Any name i could google with. I could read up resources and code it from then on. My searches so far are very disappointing and frustrating :(

Thanks much :)

Comment: I don't think there is a specific "name" for this that you could google for. _"However, if a visitor accessed the Timetable page from the Student menu tab, when the page loads, the menu should show the navigation menu under the Student tab. Likewise if a visitor accessed the page via Parent tab"_ - well, then you will need a way for your page to be able to discern those two "ways" of reaching that page - but as long as you are using the same URL in both places, you don't have any.

Comment: You could for example add a GET parameter, like `timetable?origin=student` or similar, that you can evaluate server-side when requested, so that you can add a class of `active` or whatever to the relevant menu branch. If you are not using any server-side code, then you could use JavaScript to look at the URL that the current document was requested with, and set that class dynamically on the appropriate element.

Answer (score 0):

one option i can suggest is 
well first you will need to know who got in ...create log in window with logic you desire... log in with guest choice for parents 
then you will have to create an asp file with option to check who is connected to show the right tab
(or you can create an choice bottom/input with JavaScript check)

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

look for something like 
[change Tab based on HTML Select value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15460317/change-tab-based-on-html-select-value)
on this site

it's not the full answer but it is beginning

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! :) 
But I'm not exactly looking at logging visitors in.. Its just a user select what he/she is, and be presented with a list of links appropriate to him/her.. ultimately, i'm fine if they want to view all the website has to offer..

Comment: you can choose what to show based on the logging/choice in the tab or whatever way you prefer to transfer to you the simple answer (it's the logic part)...who is browsing ...and based on the simple choice show in a simple if choice(in the code), what to show :) i hope i did explain myself